# How can ofstream write NULL to a file in binary mode?

Tags: c++, null, filestream, binaryfiles, ofstream

I am maintaining a C++ method which one of my clients is hitting an issue with. The method is supposed to write out a series of identifiers to a file delimited by a new line. However on their machine somehow the method is writing a series of NULL's out to the file. Opening the file in a binary editor shows that it contains all zeros.

I can't understand why this is happening. I've tried assigning empty strings and strings with the first character set to 0. There is no problem creating the file, just writing the identifiers to it.

Here is the method:

```
void writeIdentifiers(std::vector<std::string> IDs, std::string filename)
{   
    std::ofstream out (filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary);

    if (out.is_open())
    {
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = IDs.begin();
             it != IDs.end();
             it++)
        {
            out << *it << "\n";
        }
    }

    out.close();
}
```

My questions: is there any possible input you can provide that method which will create a file which has NULL values in it?

Comment: On a side note, why are you taking copies of objects which may be very large?  Just take a `const` reference instead.

Comment: No, because on every write you output '\n', and that definitely isn't NULL. OTOH if you mean every byte except for the newlines is NULL then obviously the answer is yes. But I would suspect something external to your code, some sort of weird hardware/firmware/file system/driver issue. These things do happen occasionally

Comment: So the generated file only contains NULL values. No newlines.

Comment: @battymatty: There is nothing in the code you showed that would do that. However, I would check the state of the stream after each write though `if(!(out << *it << '\n')) std::cout << "failed!";`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the following code quite clearly writes a series of NULL bytes:

```
std::vector<std::string> ids;
std::string nullstring;
nullstring.assign("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 10);
ids.push_back(nullstring);
writeIdentifiers(ids, "test.dat");
```

Because the `std::string` container stores the string length, it can't necessarily be used in the same way as an ordinary C (null-terminated) string.  Here, I assign a string containing 10 NULL bytes.  Those are then output because the string length is 10.

Comment: Oh, sorry...  Part of your question said "contains only NULL values", while the other part just said "contains NULL values".  I misinterpreted.  Are you looking at the file in a hex-editor to confirm that every byte is zero?

Comment: yep, was just about to say that. But that's the closest anyone's gotten.

Comment: Do you have any exception handling outside the call to `writeIdentifiers` that would silently accept any errors?  I'm thinking of buffer overruns...  For instance, if the first string is actually invalid and during write there is a memory exception thrown that would prevent the newline from being written.  This is a bit of a stretch, since you're actually copying the array passed to that function instead of passing by reference. =/

Comment: No, haven't used exceptions in this application. I believe you have to enable exceptions on streams for them to be thrown which I haven't done. I'm going do as Jesse Good suggested and add checks on the state of the stream after the write.